# Ellipsis in Circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz, ellipsis

I need to draw this TL equivalent circuit in LaTeX using circuitikz, but I don't know how to draw the ellipses. Does anybody know how to do it?

[image: Chain of inductors and capacitors with ellipses on the top and bottom rails to show that it's infinitely long]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows the code you have so far. Providing the code for just the circuit without the suspension points saves us needing to create the part of the diagram that you've already done.

Answer (score 6):

No comments again.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{bipoles/thickness =1}
\begin{document}
  \begin{circuitikz}[line width=1pt]
    \draw (0,2) to[L,l=$L'$,*-*] (2,2)
          (2,0) to[C,l=$C'$,-*] (2,2)
          (2,0) to[short,-*] (0,0)
    ;
    \begin{scope}[xshift=2cm]
    \draw (0,2) to[L,l=$L'$,*-*] (2,2)
          (2,0) to[C,l=$C'$,-*] (2,2)
          (2,0) to[short,-*] (0,0)
    ;
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[xshift=4cm]
    \draw (0,2) to[L,l=$L'$,*-*] (2,2)
          (2,0) to[C,l=$C'$,-*] (2,2)
          (2,0) to[short,-*] (0,0)
    ;
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[xshift=6cm]
    \draw (0,2) --  (2,2)node[midway,scale=2,fill=white]{$\cdots$};
    \draw (0,0) -- (2,0)node[midway,scale=2,fill=white]{$\cdots$};
    \end{scope}
    \draw (8,2) to[L,l=$L'$,-*] (10,2) to[short,-*] (11,2)
          (10,0) to[C,l=$C'$,-*] (10,2)
          (11,0) to[short,*-](10,0) to[short,*-] (8,0)
    ;
  \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can do away with `scope`s too by using proper coordinates.

Comment: +1, but too obvious with `\cdots`.. what about `\draw[loosely dotted](0,2) --  (2,2);`?

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Fair point. I was trying to  reproduce the OP's picture almost as it is. It has solid lines at left and right edges and I thought by `\cdots`, I can dispense with at least one coordinate in the middle.

Comment: Indeed, that's the perfect solution...